# Kafka Failover and Replica

Tags: apache-kafka, failover

Let's assume I have a Kafka Cluster of 3 brokers and 3 zookeeper.

I have a single topic `accountsTopic` which is setup as `replication factor of 3` and `ISR of 2`.

If the `Leader` dies, kafka will elect the `ISR` as leader, but the 3rd one, (which say for arguments sake was not ISR), is it going to serve as a ISR of current leader in this 2 node fail-over setup?

Answer (score 3):

What happens when the leader dies depends on your configuration.

By default [since 0.11](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_1100_notable), only one of the replicas in-sync can be elected as a leader. If no replicas are in-sync, the partition goes offline. This is favoring consistency over availability.

You can set `unclean.leader.election.enable=true` on your brokers and in this case, if no replicas are in-sync, one of the out-of-sync replicas will be elected. This can lead to data loss but is favoring availability. Of course if some replicas are in-sync it will still elect one of them.

Comment: In case it is not clear in the question, my `acks` setting will always ensure the ISR replica is written into before commiting the message as written. So, in short, let's assume in my case, I will always have a `ISR` replica for a clean leader election. However, I want to understand what happens to the `Non-ISR` broker after the new leader election? Does it catch up and become a `ISR` of the new leader?

Comment: An out-of-sync replica is always trying to get back in-sync by fetching data from the leader. If the leader changes, it will try to catch up from the new leader

Comment: Thanks. It will certainly try to catch up, but when a `write` happens to the new leader, is it guaranteed that the 3rd one will become new `ISR` of the new leader, so that a write to the new leader will be considered committed _only_ if the write in 3rd one also succeeds?

Comment: I think you're confused about what ISR means. ISR = In-Sync Replica. When a broker has replicated all messages from the leader it is in-sync. So yes once the 3rd broker catches up with the new leader it will become an ISR. 

Regarding writes, it depends on your settings. With acks=all, all the ISR brokers need to have replicated the message to be considered a successful send. But depending on `min.insync.replicas` and the replication factor of the topic it can require a different number of brokers. See the [broker configuration docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs)

Comment: @MickaelMaison In my test with 3 Broker, Replication factor 2, min ISR 2, ack 1. broker 0 goes down, partition remains with 1 ISR so write is not be permitted with NotEnoughReplicasException. Will another remaining broker become ISR? after how much time?
here you mentioned that [Kafka does not create a new replica when a broker goes down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132158/what-happens-after-a-broker-is-down-in-a-cluster).